# Is live modification the CSS of a website possible in a iframe or DIV?

Tags: css, html, iframe

I want to build pages that have a header bar with pages from other sites in an iframe or DIV below it.  I want to replace the CSS of the site below it with my own CSS (override it in some way; for example I may reference a blog page below it but want to change the look via CSS).  Please note these pages would only be pages whereby I would be allowed to do this based on the licensing of the site.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, not really.  Certainly not cross-domain.  The whole point of iframes is that their content is insulated from the parent page.  See [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe) for a thorough discussion of the issue.